# perl DBI, fastest way to get a single scalar value

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have this code to get a value count.

**Short way:**

```
my $count = $dbh->selectrow_array("SELECT COUNT(name) AS RESCOUNT FROM users");
```

**Long way**

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(name) AS RESCOUNT FROM users");
$sth->execute() or die "$DBI::errstr";
my $count = $sth->fetchrow_array();
$sth->finish;
```

selectrow_array, fetchrow_array --> but I don't need an array. I checked the docs, but found nothing for scalars. Just methods for arrays and hashes.
The method I use is fast enough, but I was just curious if there is a better, fastest way to get a single value from the call. Or this is the fastest possible way?

Comment: Actually the reference versions are faster than the array ones.

Comment: So, nothing new on perl DBI except the old methods. Hmm.

Comment: You are micro-optimizing. This is not where your program is wasting time. Look elsewhere. (The latter will be ever so slightly slower than the first because, while they both do the same thing, `selectrow_array` is implemented in C. )

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way is to use [`fetchrow_arrayref`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_arrayref) or [`selectrow_arrayref`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#selectrow_arrayref), depending on how many executes you have. This only really makes a difference if executed in a loop and you have thousands (or rather hundreds of thousands) of rows.

When using `fetchrow_array`, it will make a copy every time, which slows you down. Also keep in mind that the behaviour for scalar context is [only partly defined](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_arrayref).

> If called in a scalar context for a statement handle that has more than one column, it is undefined whether the driver will return the value of the first column or the last. So don't do that.

You can also do [`bind_col`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#bind_col), which works with references.

There used to be a good presentation on DBI speeds from about 10 or more years ago that I can't find right now. Also take a look at [this very old Perlmonks post](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=273952#relative), that explains quite a bit about performance.

Keep in mind that you should only do optimisation when you really know you need it. Most of the time you won't.

Comment: Also, benchmark. Posts about performance from decades ago will have little bearing on the current state of things.

Comment: Documentation is old and unchanged for years. I thought there were some new methods available, including scalar. Thanks for sharing your opinion.

Comment: @Claude there is no need to change a well-working system. But Grinnz is right. You will have to look at your specific use-case on the hardware you are using. I'll repeat my last sentence though. You only need to benchmark if it's actually slow. There is no need to make it faster if it's not too slow. Making it faster for the sake of making it faster is wasting your time.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But it is a little uncommon to fetch an array for just a simple string. On dbi documentation they advice you to be careful in scalar context, because unexpected results may occur.

Comment: @Claude. It's not uncommon. It says array, but it returns a list (because you can't return arrays in Perl). That means it makes copies of the values, which you can assign to an array. An array is in list context. It's a common idiom to assign a single value list in list context like this: `my ( $self ) = @_;`

Comment: `selectrow_arrayref` is the same C function as `selectrow_array`, and the amount of work done by both is virtually identical. There should be no noticeable difference between the two (especially here where the row only has one field). /// Similarly, `fetchrow_arrayref` and `fetchrow_arrayref` are virtually identical C functions. There should be no noticeable difference between the two (especially here where the row only has one field).

Answer (score 1):

If "modern" means "I only heard of it recently", I'm feeling all modern with DBI's bind_col and bind_columns. Cribbing from a post by DBI hero Tim Bunce...

For your case:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(name) AS RESCOUNT FROM users");
my $count = 0;
$sth->bind_col(1,\$count);  # bind to a reference to the variable
$sth->execute() or die "$DBI::errstr";
$sth->fetch;
print $count;
```

In a loop for a SELECT statement returning multiple records:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT name FROM users WHERE zip_code == '20500'});
my $name = '';
$sth->bind_col(1,\$name);  # bind to a reference to the variable
$sth->execute() or die "$DBI::errstr";
while ($sth->fetch) {
    print $name, "\n";
}
```

And with bind_columns this works:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT name,phone,address FROM users WHERE zip_code == '20500'});
my @fields = qw/name phone address/; 
# With a 'SELECT All * ...', get all columns with @{$sth->{NAME_lc}}
my %data;
$sth->bind_columns( \( @data{@fields} ) ); # \(...) gives references to its elements
$sth->execute() or die "$DBI::errstr";
while ($sth->fetch) {
    print "$data{name} lives at $data{address}, with phone $data{phone}.", "\n";
}
```

Once the setup is handled, the looping is simple to write and fast to run. (But, benchmark).

HTH, apologize if this diverges too much from the OP's problem statement. But it's the simplest and most direct way to get your returned data into the form of variable(s) you want, so you can move on to doing something with it...